# mprotect failing to recover from fifo write/read interrupt inside the fread?

Tags: c, linux, fread, mprotect

I have a simple procedure that contains 2 processes that write and read from a fifo.
I wanted to add mprotect on the buffer that the reader reads to, and then "release" it(add PROT_WRITE | READ) when there is an interrupt on it.

it seems that if I do it on a regular file(only read, not fifo) it works, but if I do it on a fifo, the reader's fread returns with error.

I am suspecting receiving interrupts inside the fifo is bad.. but it was supposed to be granted permissions.. anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of error? If it is EINTR, just restart the read.

Comment: getting bad address error and actually I see no segfault